# What is the meaning of the scapy ARP attributes

Tags: python, scapy

What do the attributes of the python scapy ARP packets mean? For example,

- `psrc`
- `pdst`
- `hwsrc`
- `hwdst`

I'm trying to understand ARP spoofing. I think:

- `pdst` is where the ARP packet should go (target),
- `psrc` is the IP to update in the target's arp table,
- `hwsrc` is the MAC corresponding to `psrc`, to update in the target's arp table
- `hwdst` is a mystery to me.

What I want to do is tell the gateway 192.168.1.254 that my MAC (`aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa`) belongs to the victim 192.168.1.100. And the reverse, to tell the victim that my mac belongs to the gateway.

So to poison the gateway I would do this:

```
srp(ARP(pdst=192.168.1.254, psrc=192.168.1.100, hwsrc=aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa))
```

is that right? Cause it's not working for me (python3.6, latest scapy, kali). That is, I see no change in the gateway's arp table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hwdst` is the destination hardware address. If you are sending an ARP "who-has" request, you should just leave it to 0 (Scapy will do that by default). This field is used in "is-at" responses.

Your command (`srp(ARP(pdst=192.168.1.254, psrc=192.168.1.100, hwsrc="aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa"))`) seems correct and should do what you want. Have you checked with Wireshark or Tcpdump how the packet you send looks like?

If you have a look at the [ARP page on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol), `hwsrc` is "Sender hardware address (SHA)", `psrc` is Sender protocol address (SPA), `hwdst` is "Target hardware address (THA)" and `pdst` is "Target protocol address  (TPA)".

Comment: thanks, I'm using scapy 2.4.0, installed with pipenv. Maybe I need to reassess my setup. So hwdst in my example would be the MAC of the gateway, correct? Was I right about the first three attributes? I looked for doc on these attributes but had no luck. If you can point me to some, I would really like to get a firm understanding. Eventually I want to understand both requests and replies. I understand that arp spoofing can be done with either. http://blog.zorinaq.com/a-more-powerful-stealthier-and-uncommon-arp-poisoning-technique/

Comment: If you want to do an ARP cache poisoning, `hwdst` should be your own MAC address. On a "normal" packet, `hwdst` should be the MAC address of the machine sending the packet.

Comment: (And you're right, you can do an ARP cache poisoning attack with a request or a reply, both should work.)

Comment: Okay, thanks. So to confirm (sorry but I'm a little dense I guess). PDST=destination of this arp packet (whose table I'm changing). PSRC=entry for the IP of the machine I want re-labeled. HWSRC=entry for the MAC address corresponding to PSRC. HWDST=entry for the MAC address corresponding to PDST

Comment: Totally, and `hwdst` is not set for a "who-has" request (which makes sense because when using ARP, the target hardware address is what you want to know).